# Реализуйте метод __len__ класса В(A)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Существует класс А, полем которого является  values. Это поле может хранить списки элементов различного типа. Класс А является родителем класса В. Реализуйте метод **len** класса В, который бы позволил получать длину (размер) поля values объекта класса B.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values
    
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,values):
        super().__init__(values)
    def __len__(self):
        return self.values
        
    pass
```

В каком месте я сделал не так?

Comment: `__len__` разве не должен возвращать длинну?

Comment: нужно получить длину, а вы что делаете?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду говоря "_размер поля_" для целочисленного поля?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.values)
```